# Use ira_laser_tools to fuse the rplidar A2 and Kinect laser scan,but the output of the merger is only kinect's data

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a rpidar A2 and a Kinect camera,i use the `ira_laser_tools`  to fuse the laser scan from the rplidar and kinect ,then use the merge data to bulid a 2d grid map by gmapping.But when i used the `rviz` to look the topic `/scan_multi`,which is the output of laserscan_multi_merger,has only a laser scan data.

i use `roslaunch  kinect_rpldiar_gmapping_demo.launch` to rosrun rplidar node and kinect node :

```
<launch>
      <!-- 3D sensor -->
      <arg name="3d_sensor" default="kinect"/>
      <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch"/>
      <!-- laser driver -->
      <arg name="laser_type" default="rplidar" />
      <include file="$(find rplidar_ros)/launch/$(arg laser_type).launch" />
      <!-- Gmapping -->
      <arg name="custom_gmapping_launch_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/gmapping/rplidar_kinect_gmapping.launch.xml"/>
      <include file="$(arg custom_gmapping_launch_file)"/>
      <!-- Move base -->
      <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>
      <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/rviz/navigation.rviz"/>

</launch>
```

and then `roslaunh  ira_laser_merge.lauch` is following:

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="ira_laser_tools" name="laserscan_multi_merger" type="laserscan_multi_merger" output="screen">
    <param name="destination_frame" value="/base_link"/>
    <param name="cloud_destination_topic" value="/merged_cloud"/>
    <param name="scan_destination_topic" value="/scan_multi"/>
    <param name="laserscan_topics" value ="/scan_kinect /scan_laser" /> 
</node>

</launch>
```

the node`laserscan_multi_merger`,it said,

`Error:"[pcl::concatenatePointCloud] Number of fields in cloud1 (4) !=Number of fields in cloud2(5)".`

cloud1 is kinect's fake laser scan;cloud2 is rplidar's laser scan.

Then i see the part-code about the `pcl::concatenatePointcloud`,which is the error comes from.(The all code is https://docs.ros.org/api/pcl_conversions/html/pcl__conversions_8h_source.html)

```
 if (!strip && cloud1.fields.size () != cloud2.fields.size ())
 {
   PCL_ERROR ("[pcl::concatenatePointCloud] Number of fields in cloud1 (%u) != Number of fields in cloud2 (%u)\n", cloud1.fields.size (), cloud2.fields.size ());
   return (false);
 }
```

So,what's the cloud.field?    meaning the kind of pointcloud?
i want to know about it .because when i look the `/scan_multi` laserscan by using rviz,there is only one data from
`/scan_kinect`.i guess ,is the question related to the abouve error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295899/use-ira_laser_tools-to-fuse-the-rplidar-a2-and-kinect-laser-scan,but-the-output-of-the-merger-is-only-kinect%27s-data./) by [skydddive](https://answers.ros.org/users/36186/skydddive/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logan.ydid](https://answers.ros.org/users/41911/logan.ydid/) on 2019-09-30**:
Im having the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're asking how to use a kinect to get a laser scan along with an rplidar?

Essentially, you need to make a node which takes in the 2 as inputs and outputs a composite laser scan which is used by gmapping. You can use the depth image to laser scan nodelet to make the laser scan for the kinect, or at least get the points for it.

From there I would probably convert the kinect points  to the laser frame ID and raytrace from the frame to find the range. You can use some geometry to get the angle. Then fill out the message with nans for positions between valid kinect readings and the rplidar you're filtering out of bounds.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skydddive](https://answers.ros.org/users/36186/skydddive/) on 2018-07-03**:
Thank you for your replying~ Yesterday,i use the ira_laser_tools to merge the fake laser data from kinect and rplidar A2' laser data.But there is a new problem.When i roslaunch the ira_laser_tools package:
"[pcl::concatenatePointCloud] Number of fields in cloud1 (4) !=Number of fields in cloud2(5)

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-07-03**:
Sounds like you need to look into the PCL documentation to understand better how to concat pointclouds. I can't do much without code to look at.

**Comment by [skydddive](https://answers.ros.org/users/36186/skydddive/) on 2018-07-03**:
there has lines(612-718) in https://docs.ros.org/api/pcl_conversions/html/pcl__conversions_8h_source.html
abou concatenatePointclould.By seeing this code,i think the error has no effect on the result about merge data ..but,the multi data has only the kinect data.